# Unable to install ldap library on python3.6

Tags: django, python-3.x, ldap

Hi i am unable to install ldap library in python 3.6. Command used is: 
pip install python-ldap

> Error:
>   pip install python-ldap
>   Collecting python-ldap pip-install-snxkbc\python-ldap\  Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/1c/28d721dff2fcd2fef9d55b40df63a00be26ec8a11e8c6fc612ae642f9cfd/python-ldap-3.1.0.tar.gz
>   Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.3.7 in
>   c:\users\dm050767\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-ldap)
>   (0.4.4) Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1_modules>=0.1.5 in
>   c:\users\dm050767\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-ldap)
>   (0.2.2) Building wheels for collected packages: python-ldap   Running
>   setup.py bdist_wheel for python-ldap ... error   Complete output from
>   command c:\users\dm050767\python27\python.exe -u -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='c:\users\dm050767\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-snxkbc\python-ldap\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d
>   c:\users\dm050767\appdata\local\temp\pip-wheel-kgoem3 --python-tag
>   cp27:   running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py
>   creating build\lib.win32-2.7   copying Lib\ldapurl.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7   copying Lib\ldif.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
>   creating build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\async.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\asyncsearch.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\cidict.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\compat.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\constants.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\dn.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\filter.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\functions.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\ldapobject.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\logger.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\modlist.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\pkginfo.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\resiter.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\sasl.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap\syncrepl.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   copying Lib\ldap__init__.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap   creating build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls 
>   copying Lib\ldap\controls\deref.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls   copying
>   Lib\ldap\controls\libldap.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>   copying Lib\ldap\controls\openldap.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls   copying
>   Lib\ldap\controls\pagedresults.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>   copying Lib\ldap\controls\ppolicy.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls   copying
>   Lib\ldap\controls\psearch.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>   copying Lib\ldap\controls\pwdpolicy.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls   copying
>   Lib\ldap\controls\readentry.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>   copying Lib\ldap\controls\sessiontrack.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls   copying
>   Lib\ldap\controls\simple.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>   copying Lib\ldap\controls\sss.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls 
>   copying Lib\ldap\controls\vlv.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls 
>   copying Lib\ldap\controls__init__.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls   creating
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\extop   copying Lib\ldap\extop\dds.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\extop   copying Lib\ldap\extop__init__.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\extop   creating
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\schema   copying Lib\ldap\schema\models.py ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\schema   copying Lib\ldap\schema\subentry.py
>   -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\schema   copying Lib\ldap\schema\tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\schema
>   copying Lib\ldap\schema__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\schema
>   creating build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest   copying
>   Lib\slapdtest_slapdtest.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest   copying
>   Lib\slapdtest__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest   running
>   egg_info   writing requirements to
>   Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\requires.txt   writing
>   Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\PKG-INFO   writing top-level names to
>   Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\top_level.txt   writing dependency_links to
>   Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\dependency_links.txt   reading manifest file
>   'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'   reading manifest template
>   'MANIFEST.in'   no previously-included directories found matching
>   'Doc.build'   writing manifest file
>   'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'   creating
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs   copying
>   Lib\slapdtest\certs\README -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>   copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.conf ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs   copying
>   Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.pem -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>   copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.conf ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs   copying
>   Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.key -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs 
>   copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.pem ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs   copying
>   Lib\slapdtest\certs\gencerts.sh -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>   copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gennssdb.sh ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs   copying
>   Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.conf -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>   copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.key ->
>   build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs   copying
>   Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.pem -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs 
>   running build_ext   building '_ldap' extension   creating
>   build\temp.win32-2.7   creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
>   creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\Modules
>   C:\Users\dm050767\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++
>   for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG
>   -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=3.1.0 "-DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project" "-DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style" -IModules
>   -Ic:\users\dm050767\python27\include -Ic:\users\dm050767\python27\PC /TcModules/LDAPObject.c
>   /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj   LDAPObject.c 
>   c:\users\dm050767\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-snxkbc\python-ldap\modules\constants.h(7)
>   : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file
>   or directory   error: command
>   'C:\Users\dm050767\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>
> ----------------------------------------   Failed building wheel for
>   python-ldap   Running setup.py clean for python-ldap Failed to build
>   python-ldap Installing collected packages: python-ldap   Running
>   setup.py install for python-ldap ... error
>       Complete output from command c:\users\dm050767\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\dm050767\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-snxkbc\python-ldap\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record c:\users\dm050767\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-uvc2cf\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build\lib.win32-2.7
>       copying Lib\ldapurl.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
>       copying Lib\ldif.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
>       creating build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\async.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\asyncsearch.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\cidict.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\constants.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\dn.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\filter.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\functions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\ldapobject.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\logger.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\modlist.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\pkginfo.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\resiter.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\sasl.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap\syncrepl.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       copying Lib\ldap__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap
>       creating build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\deref.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\libldap.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\openldap.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\pagedresults.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\ppolicy.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\psearch.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\pwdpolicy.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\readentry.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\sessiontrack.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\simple.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\sss.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls\vlv.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       copying Lib\ldap\controls__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\controls
>       creating build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\extop
>       copying Lib\ldap\extop\dds.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\extop
>       copying Lib\ldap\extop__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\extop
>       creating build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\schema
>       copying Lib\ldap\schema\models.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\schema
>       copying Lib\ldap\schema\subentry.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\schema
>       copying Lib\ldap\schema\tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\schema
>       copying Lib\ldap\schema__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\ldap\schema
>       creating build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest
>       copying Lib\slapdtest_slapdtest.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest
>       copying Lib\slapdtest__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest
>       running egg_info
>       writing requirements to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\requires.txt
>       writing Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\PKG-INFO
>       writing top-level names to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\top_level.txt
>       writing dependency_links to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
>       reading manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>       reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
>       no previously-included directories found matching 'Doc.build'
>       writing manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>       creating build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\README -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.conf -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.pem -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.conf -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.key -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.pem -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gencerts.sh -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gennssdb.sh -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.conf -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.key -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.pem -> build\lib.win32-2.7\slapdtest\certs
>       running build_ext
>       building '_ldap' extension
>       creating build\temp.win32-2.7
>       creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
>       creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\Modules
>       C:\Users\dm050767\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG
>   -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=3.1.0 "-DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project" "-DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style" -IModules
>   -Ic:\users\dm050767\python27\include -Ic:\users\dm050767\python27\PC /TcModules/LDAPObject.c
>   /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
>       LDAPObject.c
>       c:\users\dm050767\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-snxkbc\python-ldap\modules\constants.h(7)
>   : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file
>   or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Users\dm050767\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "c:\users\dm050767\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
> ```
>
> tokenize;**file**='c:\users\dm050767\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-snxkbc\python-ldap\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record c:\users\dm050767\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-uvc2cf\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   c:\users\dm050767\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-snxkbc\python-ldap\

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to install dependencies required for Ubuntu/Debian are the following:

1)libldap2-dev

2)libsasl2-dev

3)slapd

4)ldap-utils

In my own case, I install it in my Dockerfile  using the following command:

***sudo apt-get update***

***sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y  libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev slapd ldap-utils***

and finally, try to install LDAP by using

***pip install django-auth-ldap***

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download from the official source from Pypi repository (this too supports installing through pip)

```
$ python3 -m pip install python-ldap
```

Comment: error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program

Comment: (__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\dm050767\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-68gh24b2\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\dm050767\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1nvbn842\python-ldap\

Answer (score 0):

On 2022-09-20, I was able to install the renamed package: ldap3  (formerly python-ldap) using (the trusted-host parameter is required by my org)

pip install ldap3 --trusted-host pypi.org

Comment: Rather than providing the date, consider providing package version etc to make the answer clearer. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).